# Bootstrap Navbar gets stuck on mobile

Tags: html, ios, css, twitter-bootstrap, cordova

I'm using Cordova to build a cross-platform app. I'm using bootstrap for my framework and I'm running into some trouble with the navbar. I'm not using any special CSS for it or anything. Here is my code:

```
<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
<div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Header</a>
    </div>
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#about">Terms & Conditions</a></li>
            <li><a id="logout">Logout</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <!--/.nav-collapse -->
</div>
```

Here is my viewport settings in case that matters:

```
    <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=medium-dpi"/>
```

When the keyboard is shown (when I'm inside a text field), the navbar gets pushed up. If I click a button while the keyboard is open, the keyboard disappears and the navbar gets stuck halfway down the page (I'm guessing where it was when the keyboard was up). I've made a screen recording of it to better explain. It's here: https://vid.me/zIc

Also, in Cordova I have "DisallowOverscroll=true" so you can't scroll if there is no need. If I have this set to false, it still happens, but if I scroll even the slightest bit, it jumps into place!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems as though it WAS my viewport settings. I removed the "height=device-height" and it seems to work now!